# I'm having an XA_END error while trying to send a message from my banking application T24 to WMQ through my application server JBOSS

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

I'm setting up the Banking application I use(T24) to send and receive messages from IBM MQ. I'm getting errors when I connect my application server(JBOSS 7) to MQ

I've tried altering the MDB's but to no avail.

This is a snippet from my Log file:

```
2019-03-22 17:00:17,269 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RaXmlDeployer] (default-threads - 13) wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4026:Transaction backed out with reason: 'The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '100'.'.
2019-03-22 17:00:17,269 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (default-threads - 24) IJ000612: Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@213a8b6c[state=NORMAL managed connection=com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionImpl@3db98551 connection handles=0 lastReturned=1553274017260 lastValidated=1553274017260 lastCheckedOut=1553274017260 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@2185ef44 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@52753b07[pool=WMQ Connection Pool] xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@518c200e[xaResource=com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper@67583e6a pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=IBM MQ productVersion=@(#) MQMBID sn=p910-L180709.TRIAL su=_QGElQYNUEeidSaRkJ_p2Kg pn=com.ibm.mq.connector/src/com/ibm/mq/connector/outbound/ManagedConnectionMetaDataImpl.java jndiName=java:jboss/jms/MQConnectionFactory] txSync=null]
2019-03-22 17:00:17,269 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (default-threads - 13) ARJUNA016045: attempted rollback of < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffffc0a81701:-783f63b7:5c951441:40a3, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffffc0a81701:-783f63b7:5c951441:40b4, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/jms/MQConnectionFactory > (XAResourceWrapperImpl@44eb1bdd[xaResource=com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper@c57055e pad=false overrideRmValue=null productName=IBM MQ productVersion=@(#) MQMBID sn=p910-L180709.TRIAL su=_QGElQYNUEeidSaRkJ_p2Kg pn=com.ibm.mq.connector/src/com/ibm/mq/connector/outbound/ManagedConnectionMetaDataImpl.java jndiName=java:jboss/jms/MQConnectionFactory]) failed with exception code XAException.XAER_NOTA: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_rollback' has failed with errorCode '-4'.



    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.rollback(JmqiXAResource.java:874)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.xa.XARWrapper.rollback(XARWrapper.java:605)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.rollback(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:196)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelAbort(XAResourceRecord.java:369)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:2999)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.doAbort(BasicAction.java:2978)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.Abort(BasicAction.java:1658)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.cancel(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:127)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.abort(AtomicAction.java:186)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.rollbackAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1282)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.rollback(BaseTransaction.java:143)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.rollback(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.afterDelivery(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.doInvoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:135)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at com.temenos.tafj.mdb.TransactedMDB$$$endpoint1.afterDelivery(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.AbstractWorkImpl.run(AbstractWorkImpl.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:223)
    at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:808)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:849)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error can be safely ignored.

```
    XAER_NOTA is a valid return from xa_rollback()
    The XA specification indicates that "[a]n RM can also unilaterally roll back and forget a branch any time except after a successful prepare"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Doug. Although, its difficult to ignore because my JBOSS keeps on looping with the same error, and my log file fills up to more than 1 Gigabyte due to the incessant looping. Also, Any message I manually put into one of my queues, gets moved to my Back-Out queue immediately jboss loads and connects with MQ. My Banking software also doesn't successfully send any message to MQ while JBOSS has connected. It's all strange to me because I just started using MQ and thought that after successfully connecting it to JBOSS and my application through those MDB setups, It'd work.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, you can see the 'afterDelivery()'.  This means that the MDBs 'onMessage()' has returned.  The transaction is then being rolled back.  This means that the transaction was either marked in the code as being rollback only, or some exception occurred that caused the transaction to be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Doug. I really appreciate it. A few more questions please. Any idea what could be causing the Transaction to rollback? I've been searching online, but I've not really been able to find out what causes the errors:1(xa_end has failed with error code '100')     2.(ARJUNA016045: attempted rollback of <*****failed with exception code XAException.XAER_NOTA: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_rollback' has failed with errorCode '-4')       3.(IJ000612: Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener*****)

Comment: The "Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched" is actually due to a bug in the IBM JCA client code.  The transaction match check on the JMS session wasn't working correctly.  I think that this was fixed in 8.0.0.4, but then popped up again in 8.0.0.10.

Comment: Wow. How about this error: wmq.jmsra.rar: MQJCA4026:Transaction backed out with reason: 'The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '100'.' That seems to be the genesis of the problem.

Comment: Update: My JBOSS was looping incessantly with the same error, because I replaced the default resource adapter in Jboss with My WMQ resource adapter. When I changed it back to the default Resource Adapter, it stopped looping.